# JAVA GUI distance converter not converting using radio buttons

Tags: java, swing

when you run the file it will work until you put a number in the text field and then it breaks and says empty string. I just need help with this part. I use 1 inch in the inches field to convert to centimeters. i have the rest commented out just to test and focus on centimeters. without the comments it still crashes the same way.  the issue seems to be from line 529 area which is the action listener. any and all help would be wonderful and appriciated

```
package hardingconversiongui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class GuiConversion extends JFrame {

private JPanel panel1;                  // A holding panel
private JPanel panel2;
private JPanel panel3;
private JPanel panel4;
private JPanel panel5;
private JPanel panel6;
private JPanel panel7;
private JPanel panel8;
private JPanel panel9;
private JPanel panel10;
private JPanel panel11;
private JLabel messageLabel;
private JTextField textField;
private ButtonGroup radioButtonGroup;
private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 900;
private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 900;
private JRadioButton centimetersButton;
private JRadioButton metersButton;
private JRadioButton yardsButton;
private JRadioButton milesButton;
private JRadioButton feetButton;
private JRadioButton inchesButton;
private JRadioButton kilometersButton;
private JRadioButton squaremetersButton;
private JRadioButton squareyardsButton;
private JRadioButton squarefeetButton;
private JRadioButton squareinchesButton;
private JRadioButton cubicfeetButton;
private JRadioButton cubicinchesButton;
private JRadioButton cubicmetersButton;
private JRadioButton cubicyardsButton;
private JRadioButton ouncesButton;
private JRadioButton kilogramsButton;
private JRadioButton poundsButton;
private JRadioButton gramsButton;
private JRadioButton quartsButton;
private JRadioButton pintsButton;
private JRadioButton cupsButton;
private JRadioButton gallonsButton;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public GuiConversion() {
    // Set the title.
    setTitle("CONVERTER");

    // Set the size of the window.
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    setLayout(new GridLayout(11, 1));

    // Specify an action for the close button.
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Build the panel and add it to the frame.
    buildPanel1();

    // Add the panel to the frame's content pane.
    add(panel1);

    buildPanel2();
    add(panel2);

    buildPanel3();
    add(panel3);

    buildPanel4();
    add(panel4);

    buildPanel5();
    add(panel5);

    buildPanel6();
    add(panel6);

    buildPanel7();
    add(panel7);

    buildPanel8();
    add(panel8);

    buildPanel9();
    add(panel9);

    buildPanel10();
    add(panel10);

    buildPanel11();
    add(panel11);

    // Display the window.
    setVisible(true);

}

/**
 * The buildPanel method adds a label, text field, and and three buttons to
 * a panel.
 */
private void buildPanel1() {
    // Create the label, text field, and radio buttons.
    messageLabel = new JLabel("Enter inches");
    textField  = new JTextField(10);
    centimetersButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to centimeters");
    metersButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to meters");
    feetButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to feet");
    yardsButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to yards");
    kilometersButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to kilometers");

    // Group the radio buttons.
    radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    radioButtonGroup.add(centimetersButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(metersButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(feetButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(yardsButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(kilometersButton);

    // Add action listeners to the radio buttons.
    centimetersButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    metersButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    feetButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    yardsButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    kilometersButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

    // Create a panel and add the components to it.
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.add(messageLabel);
    panel1.add(textField);
    panel1.add(centimetersButton);
    panel1.add(metersButton);
    panel1.add(feetButton);
    panel1.add(yardsButton);
    panel1.add(kilometersButton);
}

private void buildPanel2() {
    // Create the label, text field, and radio buttons.
    messageLabel = new JLabel("Enter feet");
    textField = new JTextField(10);
    metersButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to meters");
    yardsButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to yards");
    kilometersButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to kilometers");
    milesButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to miles");

    // Group the radio buttons.
    radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    radioButtonGroup.add(metersButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(yardsButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(kilometersButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(milesButton);

    // Add action listeners to the radio buttons.
    metersButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    yardsButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    kilometersButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    milesButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    // Create a panel and add the components to it.
    panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.add(messageLabel);
    panel2.add(textField);
    panel2.add(metersButton);
    panel2.add(yardsButton);
    panel2.add(kilometersButton);
    panel2.add(milesButton);
}

private void buildPanel3() {
    messageLabel = new JLabel("Enter yards");
    textField = new JTextField(10);
    metersButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to meters");
    feetButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to feet");
    kilometersButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to kilometers");
    milesButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to miles");

    radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    radioButtonGroup.add(metersButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(feetButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(kilometersButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(milesButton);

    metersButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    feetButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    kilometersButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    milesButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

    panel3 = new JPanel();
    panel3.add(messageLabel);
    panel3.add(textField);
    panel3.add(metersButton);
    panel3.add(feetButton);
    panel3.add(kilometersButton);
    panel3.add(milesButton);
}

private void buildPanel4() {
    messageLabel = new JLabel("Enter square yards");
    textField = new JTextField(10);
    squareinchesButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to square inches");
    squaremetersButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to square meters");
    squarefeetButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to square feet");

    radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    radioButtonGroup.add(squareinchesButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(squaremetersButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(squarefeetButton);

    squareinchesButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    squaremetersButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    squarefeetButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

    panel4 = new JPanel();
    panel4.add(messageLabel);
    panel4.add(textField);
    panel4.add(squareinchesButton);
    panel4.add(squaremetersButton);
    panel4.add(squarefeetButton);
}

private void buildPanel5() {
    messageLabel = new JLabel("Enter square miles");
    textField = new JTextField(10);
    squareinchesButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to square inches");
    squarefeetButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to square feet");
    squareyardsButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to square yards");

    radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    radioButtonGroup.add(squareinchesButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(squarefeetButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(squareyardsButton);

    squareinchesButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    squarefeetButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    squareyardsButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

    panel5 = new JPanel();
    panel5.add(messageLabel);
    panel5.add(textField);
    panel5.add(squareinchesButton);
    panel5.add(squarefeetButton);
    panel5.add(squareyardsButton);
}

private void buildPanel6() {
    messageLabel = new JLabel("Enter cubic feet");
    textField = new JTextField(10);
    cubicinchesButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to cubic inches");
    cubicmetersButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to cubic meters");
    cubicyardsButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to cubic yards");

    // Group the radio buttons.
    radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    radioButtonGroup.add(cubicinchesButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(cubicmetersButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(cubicyardsButton);
    ;
    cubicinchesButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    cubicmetersButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    cubicyardsButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

    // Create a panel and add the components to it.
    panel6 = new JPanel();
    panel6.add(messageLabel);
    panel6.add(textField);
    panel6.add(cubicinchesButton);
    panel6.add(cubicmetersButton);
    panel6.add(cubicyardsButton);
}

private void buildPanel7() {
    messageLabel = new JLabel("Enter cubic yards");
    textField = new JTextField(10);
    cubicinchesButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to cubic inches");
    cubicmetersButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to cubic meters");
    cubicfeetButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to cubic feet");

    // Group the radio buttons.
    radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    radioButtonGroup.add(cubicinchesButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(cubicmetersButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(cubicfeetButton);

    cubicinchesButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    cubicmetersButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    cubicfeetButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

    panel7 = new JPanel();
    panel7.add(messageLabel);
    panel7.add(textField);
    panel7.add(cubicinchesButton);
    panel7.add(cubicmetersButton);
    panel7.add(cubicfeetButton);
}

private void buildPanel8() {
    messageLabel = new JLabel("Enter ounces");
    textField = new JTextField(10);
    kilogramsButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to kilograms");
    poundsButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to pounds");
    gramsButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to grams");

    // Group the radio buttons.
    radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    radioButtonGroup.add(kilogramsButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(poundsButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(gramsButton);

    kilogramsButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    poundsButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    gramsButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

    panel8 = new JPanel();
    panel8.add(messageLabel);
    panel8.add(textField);
    panel8.add(kilogramsButton);
    panel8.add(poundsButton);
    panel8.add(gramsButton);
}

private void buildPanel9() {
    messageLabel = new JLabel("Enter pounds");
    textField = new JTextField(10);
    kilogramsButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to kilograms");
    ouncesButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to ounces");
    gramsButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to grams");

    radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    radioButtonGroup.add(kilogramsButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(ouncesButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(gramsButton);

    kilogramsButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    ouncesButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    gramsButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

    panel9 = new JPanel();
    panel9.add(messageLabel);
    panel9.add(textField);
    panel9.add(kilogramsButton);
    panel9.add(ouncesButton);
    panel9.add(gramsButton);
}

private void buildPanel10() {
    messageLabel = new JLabel("Enter pints");
    textField = new JTextField(10);
    ouncesButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to ounces");
    cupsButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to cups");
    quartsButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to quarts");
    gallonsButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to gallons");

    radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    radioButtonGroup.add(ouncesButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(cupsButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(quartsButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(gallonsButton);

    ouncesButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    cupsButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    quartsButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    gallonsButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

    panel10 = new JPanel();
    panel10.add(messageLabel);
    panel10.add(textField);
    panel10.add(ouncesButton);
    panel10.add(cupsButton);
    panel10.add(quartsButton);
    panel10.add(gallonsButton);
}

private void buildPanel11() {
    messageLabel = new JLabel("Enter quarts");
    textField = new JTextField(10);
    ouncesButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to ounces");
    pintsButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to pints");
    cupsButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to cups");
    gallonsButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to gallons");

    radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    radioButtonGroup.add(ouncesButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(pintsButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(cupsButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(gallonsButton);

    ouncesButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    pintsButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    cupsButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    gallonsButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

    panel11 = new JPanel();
    panel11.add(messageLabel);
    panel11.add(textField);
    panel11.add(ouncesButton);
    panel11.add(pintsButton);
    panel11.add(cupsButton);
    panel11.add(gallonsButton);
}

/**
 * Private inner class that handles the event when the user clicks one of
 * the radio buttons.
 */
private class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String input;          // To hold the user's input
        String convertTo = ""; // The units we're converting to
        double convertingNumber = 0.0;   // To hold the conversion

        // Get the inches entered.
        input = textField.getText();
        // Determine which radio button was clicked.
        if (e.getSource() == centimetersButton) {
            convertTo = "centimeters.";
            convertingNumber = Double.parseDouble(input) * 2.54;
        }/* else if (e.getSource() == metersButton) {

            convertTo = " meters.";
            convertingNumber = Double.parseDouble(input) * .0254;
        } else if (e.getSource() == feetButton) {

            convertTo = " feet.";
            convertingNumber = Double.parseDouble(input) / 12;
        } else if (e.getSource() == yardsButton) {

            convertTo = " yards.";
            convertingNumber = Double.parseDouble(input) / 36;
        } else if (e.getSource() == kilometersButton) {
            // Convert to miles.
            convertTo = " kilometers.";
            convertingNumber = Double.parseDouble(input) * 0.0000254;
        }*/

        // Display the conversion.
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, convertingNumber );
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GuiConversion guiConversion = new GuiConversion();
}
}
```

Comment: Well, that first question you need to answer is, which field is actually the input field.  Because you've attached an `ActionListener`, every time you select on, it will trigger the `ActionListener`, regardless of what's entered in the text field. A better solution might be to have a "convert" button which which triggered, checks what's selected and read the value from the text field. You should also check to see if the input is empty or not before trying to convert the value

Comment: You can't use the same variable `textField` in every panel. You need different variables for everything, otherwise you are just overriding each 'buildPanelx' in the next one. If you comment out all buildPanels but the first one in the constructor, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are building your screen, you are using 1 variable for textField. You use it to create a new TextField and then add that to panel 1. then you use it to create a new TextField (losing the reference to the last one). This repeats until you get to the last one. That means when you get your "input" value from the "textField" object, it is only looking at the last one you made (the last one on the screen). You need to make separate variables, one for each TextField. textInches, textFeet, textYards, etc.

UPDATE: Here is some code that might help straighten you out.

```
package net.bcr666.javatest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GuiConversion extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JRadioButton rdoLength = new JRadioButton("Length");
private JRadioButton rdoArea = new JRadioButton("Area");
private JRadioButton rdoVolume = new JRadioButton("Volume");
private JRadioButton rdoWeight = new JRadioButton("Weight");
private JRadioButton rdoLiquidVolume = new JRadioButton("Liquid Volume");

ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
{
    group.add(rdoLength);
    group.add(rdoArea);
    group.add(rdoVolume);
    group.add(rdoWeight);
    group.add(rdoLiquidVolume);
    rdoLength.setSelected(true);
}

CardLayout layoutCard = new CardLayout();
JPanel pnlCard = new JPanel(layoutCard);

public GuiConversion() {
// Set the title.
setTitle("CONVERTER");

setLayout(new BorderLayout());

// Specify an action for the close button.
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

getContentPane().add(buildSelectionPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
getContentPane().add(pnlCard, BorderLayout.CENTER);

pnlCard.add(buildLengthPanel(), "LENGTH");
pnlCard.add(buildAreaPanel(), "AREA");
pnlCard.add(buildVolumePanel(), "VOLUME");
pnlCard.add(buildWeightPanel(), "WEIGHT");
pnlCard.add(buildLiquidVolumePanel(), "LIQUID VOLUME");

rdoLength.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        layoutCard.show(pnlCard, "LENGTH");
    }
});
rdoArea.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        layoutCard.show(pnlCard, "AREA");
    }
});
rdoVolume.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        layoutCard.show(pnlCard, "VOLUME");
    }
});
rdoWeight.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        layoutCard.show(pnlCard, "WEIGHT");
    }
});
rdoLiquidVolume.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        layoutCard.show(pnlCard, "LIQUID VOLUME");
    }
});

pack();
// Display the window.
setVisible(true);
}

private JPanel buildSelectionPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    panel.add(new JLabel("Please select conversion type"));
    panel.add(rdoLength);
    panel.add(rdoArea);
    panel.add(rdoVolume);
    panel.add(rdoWeight);
    panel.add(rdoLiquidVolume);

    return panel;
}

private JPanel buildLengthPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    String[] inputTypes = {"Inches","Feet","Yards"};
    JComboBox<String> cboInputType = new JComboBox<>(inputTypes);
    JTextField txtInputLength = new JTextField(10);
    String[] convertTypes = {"Centimeters","Meters","Feet","Yards","Kilometers"};
    JComboBox<String> cboConvertType = new JComboBox<>(convertTypes);
    JTextField txtConvertLength = new JTextField(10);
    txtConvertLength.setEnabled(false);
    JLabel lblConvertType = new JLabel();
    JButton btnConvertLength = new JButton("Convert");
    btnConvertLength.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                txtConvertLength.setText("");
                lblConvertType.setText("");
                double inputLength = Double.parseDouble(txtInputLength.getText());
                String strInputType = (String) cboInputType.getSelectedItem();
                String strConvertType = (String) cboConvertType.getSelectedItem();
                double convertFactor = 0.0d;
                if ("Inches".equals(strInputType)) {
                    if ("Centimeters".equals(strConvertType)) {
                        convertFactor = 2.54;
                    } else if ("Meters".equals(strConvertType)) {
                        convertFactor = 0.0254;
                    } else if ("Kilometers".equals(strConvertType)) {
                        convertFactor = 0.0000254;
                    } else if ("Inches".equals(strConvertType)) {
                        convertFactor = 1.0;
                    } else if ("Feet".equals(strConvertType)) {
                        convertFactor = 0.0833333;
                    } else if ("Yards".equals(strConvertType)) {
                        convertFactor = 0.0277778;
                    }
                } else if ("Feet".equals(strInputType)) {
                    // some conversion
                } else if ("Yards".equals(strInputType)) {
                    // some conversion
                }

                double convertLength = inputLength * convertFactor;
                txtConvertLength.setText(Double.toString(convertLength));
                lblConvertType.setText(strConvertType);
                GuiConversion.this.pack(); // resize the frame to account for added text
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // could not convert text to number, should probably warn the user
            }
        }
    });

    panel.add(new JLabel("Convert "));
    panel.add(txtInputLength);
    panel.add(cboInputType);
    panel.add(new JLabel(" to "));
    panel.add(cboConvertType);
    panel.add(btnConvertLength);
    panel.add(new JLabel(" = "));
    panel.add(txtConvertLength);
    panel.add(lblConvertType);

    return panel;
}

private JPanel buildAreaPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    panel.add(new JLabel("Area"));

    return panel;
}

private JPanel buildVolumePanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    panel.add(new JLabel("Volume"));

    return panel;
}

private JPanel buildWeightPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    panel.add(new JLabel("Weight"));

    return panel;
}

private JPanel buildLiquidVolumePanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    panel.add(new JLabel("Liwuid Volume"));

    return panel;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GuiConversion guiConversion = new GuiConversion();
}
}
```